# Записать в список математическое выражение python

Tags: python, list

Есть легальный способ записать в list мат.выражение?

из этого:

> a = 1 + 2 + 3

сделать это:

> a = [1, +, 2, +, 3]

Это нужно, что бы можно было запросить у пользователя выражение целиком для калькулятора. Потому что, как реализовать, что бы калькулятор принимал сразу все выражение, я не нашел.
(eval не предлагать)

Comment: А вы с какой целью интересуетесь? Есть много разных вариантов - в виде символов/строк записать, например. Но можно и сами методы записать, вопрос в том, что вы с ними дальше собираетесь делать, зачем вам этот список - от этого будет зависеть и ответ на ваш вопрос. Но прямо вот в таком в точности виде, без кавычек - так нельзя.

Comment: Кроме того, выражение `a = 1 + 2 + 3` любой адекватный интерпретатор питона сразу оптимизирует до `a = 6`, такое выражение в результате просто физически не будет присутствовать в коде программы и "восстановить" эти слагаемые будет невозможно.

Comment: Буду принимать целое мат.выражение и передавать в калькулятор, что бы не просить: введите первое число, введите второе число

Comment: Нет смысла писать выражение в список. Вам вероятно нужен [tokenizer](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9B%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%81%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B9_%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%B7#%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%80) - процедура которая из строки порождает токены - минимальные лексические единицы имеющие самостоятельный смысл.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если я правильно понял. Можно записывать с любым числом пробелов или вообще без них:

```
expr = "1 + 2 + 3"
lst = [x for x in list(expr) if x.strip()]
print(lst)
```

Вывод:

```
['1', '+', '2', '+', '3']
```

Ещё один "функциональный" вариант (без спискового сокращения, одни функции):

```
lst = list(filter(len, map(str.strip, expr)))
```

Результат будет тот же.

Хотя это сработает только для одиночных чисел...

Answer (score 1):

Можно воспользоваться регулярными выражениями, чтобы вычленить параметры выражения и операторы для них:

```
import re
var = '1 - 2 + 3 - 4'
expr = re.findall('([+-]?)\s*([\d]+)', var)
print(expr)  # [('', '1'), ('-', '2'), ('+', '3'), ('-', '4')]
```

Потом можно пройтись по списку кортежей, где на первом месте у нас оператор, а на втором значение для него, и какой-нибудь функцией собрать результат.

Answer (score 0):

Используй `rsplit`

```
a = input("Выражение \n")
if " " in a:
    b = a.rsplit(' ')
    print(b)
else:
    a = " ".join(a)  
    b = a.rsplit(' ')
    print(b)
```

Comment: А если a =  1+2+3 (без пробелов)

Comment: Вот, теперь так и так работает @Beger

Comment: Да не работает, конечно. Если пробелы расставить как попало, то и получится совсем не то, что надо. Пример: ``1- 5+9- 7``

Answer (score -2):

`a=(1+y)*(x+(y/(x**2+4))/(math.exp(2)+(1/(x**2+4))))`

Comment: В текущем виде ваш ответ непонятен. Пожалуйста, нажмите [edit] под сообщением, чтобы добавить больше подробностей, которые помогут другим понять, как он отвечает на заданный вопрос. Вы можете найти больше информации о том, как писать хорошие ответы в [Справке](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Пожалуйста, старайтесь писать более развёрнутые ответы. Отредактировать ответ можно кнопкой [edit].